# How to change the size of Google's Material design date picker?

Tags: html, css, datepicker, materialize

I am using Google's Materialize css date picker and it opens as a big pop over. I want to reduce the size I tried the following css code, but it does not work.

HTML:

```
<input value="" id="date1" type="text" class="validate important datepicker">
```

CSS:

```
.dp-calendar-day {
    width: 35px !important;
    height: 30px !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
d.addEventListener('click',function () {
    /* body... */
    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
        today: 'Today',
        clear: 'Clear',
        close: 'Ok',
        closeOnSelect: false // Close upon selecting a date,
    });
})
```

Comment: include the link for css and js file that was used.

Comment: I did mention the ncessary css and javascript section there.